# Celery worker hangs when an exception is raised

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task

I've a django app with a bunch of celery tasks which get repeated for a list of arguments. The tasks are defined using the `shared_task` decorator and I use rabbitmq for backend. If any of the tasks raises an exception, the worker freezes and none of the remaining tasks get executed. Here's a sample task:

```
@shared_task
def my_task(table_name:str):
  conn = get_sqlalchemy_engine()
  try:
     conn.execute("SELECT * from " + table_name +;")
  except e:
     raise e
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55542291/unhandled-exception-in-celery-freezes-workers) but that doesn't seem to be my case. I do not want the failed task to be re-attempted, or an email sent or anything. I simply want the worker to move on to the next task in the queue. Is there a task-level or worker level configuration I can set to this effect?

Comment: Which concurrency type is used by your worker(s)?

Comment: Could you provide some worker logs?. Also you are missing a double quote `conn.execute("SELECT * from " + table_name + ";")`